# Using Map To Create Components - but functions are tied to each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a bunch of dynamically filled dropdown menues.

```
unitMap = [[Unit1, Chapter1, Chapter2], [Unit2, Chapter3]]

let dropDownUnit = props.unitMap.map((unit, index) => {
    let unitName = unit[0];
    console.log(unit) // prints [Unit1, Chapter1, Chapter2] the first map, then [Unit2, Chapter3] the second map

    return (
        <List
          component="nav"
          aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
          subheader={
              <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader" />
          }
          className={classes.root}
          key={index}
          >
              <ListItem button onClick={handleClick} >
                  <ListItemText primary={unitName} />
                  {!open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
              </ListItem>
              {/* {dropdownChap} */}
        </List>
    )
  })
```

This is the resulting render: [What is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk55r.png)

It looks like the JSX is properly rendering the mapped components, but for some reason the onClick function is binded to both dropdowns, clicking either one of them will cause both/all dropdowns to collapse/expand. This defeats the purpose I am trying to achieve, by making all dropdowns independent from each other and I dont understand why this is happening.

Comment: handleClick reference is same for all ListItems, move handleClick function into the map function or use as arrow function so that handleClick will be new for every ListItem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one state control for all your items, you should have open controls for how many different items you want to control.

```
 <ListItem button onClick={handleClick} >
              <ListItemText primary={unitName} />
              {!open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
    </ListItem>
```

**'open'** is the same for all items.

My suggestion is to get the index and handle the click only for that current index.

```
<ListItem button onClick={handleClick(index)}
{!`open${index}` ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
```

Comment: I tried changing open to a locally instantiated variable whenever a new component is created, with a global function to handle the click, however this is resulting in an infinite render loop. What exactly is the problem? (altnernatively, how do i fix the problem mentionend in your solution?)

Comment: can you try onClick={() => handleClick(index)} ?

Comment: I swapped index with my locally instantiated variable, but after i added this bit of code, it did stop the infinite loading, however now my dropdown menues are unresponsive to my state changes.

Comment: I believe this is another issues. Can you post a new one to treat it?

Comment: Yes I will create a new posting for the follow up problem and I will link it here tagging you, however I think due to my account lifespan, I have to wait 90 minutes to post again. :(

Comment: Sure! I'll love to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220937/discussion-between-jeffrey-and-monique-altero).